# How can I know a block level element spans multiple lines or sigle line

Tags: html, css

I am new to css. I am reading about block-level elements.
"div" is a block level element.
"p" is also a block level element.

"Browsers typically display the block-level element with a newline both before and after the element. You can visualize them as a stack of boxes"
from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements

But when using "div", I can see that it does not add a new line unlike other block level elements like "p" or "h1".

I mean I could see a difference with the following code snippets

```html
<p> Text1</p> 
<p> Text2 </p>
```

```html
<div> Text1</div> 
<div> Text2 </div>
```

In the 1st code snippet, a new line is added after a "p" element.
In the 2nd code snippet, a new line is not added after "div" element.

So why "div" is not adding a new line? Can anyone please help in understanding this?

Comment: I read your post multiple times and still, I don't understand what you mean. Please do a codepen to explain your misunderstanding.

Comment: It should be displaying as a block. Share some code as an example 

https://codepen.io/theomjones/pen/OxZrza

Comment: i bet you mean margin/padding....

Comment: I think you're confusing the default margin and padding a browser gives to different elements with block level

Comment: Yes, now I understand the concept. I got confused with the default margins added by browser with a new line. Thank you all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no such thing as *"new line"* only default margins that are  applied to elements like H1 and P.

want to null them?

```
body, p, h1, h2 /* etc*/ { margin: 0; }
```

Exactly. DIV has no default user-agent margins.

Answer (score 1):

"I can see that it does not add a new line unlike other block level elements"

There is no new line. It's just that `p` and `h1` may have default `padding`/`margin` which makes separates it from other content;

The following snippet displays two `p` and two `div` elements with default `padding` and `margin`

```css
p { background-color: #8ABB55; }

div { background-color: #8BFB55; }
```

```html
<p>This paragraph is a block-level element; its background has been colored to display the paragraph's parent element.</p>

<p>This paragraph is a block-level element; its background has been colored to display the paragraph's parent element.</p>

<div>This paragraph is a block-level element; its background has been colored to display the paragraph's parent element.</div>

<div>This paragraph is a block-level element; its background has been colored to display the paragraph's parent element.</div>
```

Now for the same html, the following snippet displays the two `p` and the two `divs` with no `padding` and `margin` for the `p` this time

```css
p {
  background-color: #8ABB55;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  background-color: #8BFB55;
}
```

```html
<p>This paragraph is a block-level element; its background has been colored to display the paragraph's parent element.</p>

<p>This paragraph is a block-level element; its background has been colored to display the paragraph's parent element.</p>

<div>This paragraph is a block-level element; its background has been colored to display the paragraph's parent element.</div>

<div>This paragraph is a block-level element; its background has been colored to display the paragraph's parent element.</div>
```

You can see that now the `p` is no different than your default `div`

Answer (score 1):

Newline means that block-level elements start in the next line following the normal flow of the document, that's one of the differences between for example `div` and `span`:

> Generally, block-level elements begin on new lines, inline elements do
>   not.

From https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.3

As other users explain, it's not a gap between yhe block and other elements, the space is given by margins or paddings. But a block-level element like div, unless is set to display as inline-block or is out of the normal flow of the document with position or float, starts in a new line.